# Manage content on multiple pages synchronysly?

Tags: pages

Is there any way to use the same content blocks on mutliple pages?

For example, I have a website that focuses on services for different cities.
80% of the content ist the same. If I have 50 pages for 50 cities, and one part of the content needs to be edited, I have to edit all 50 manually.

Is there any faster way?

Comment: You could use a template? Then you'd only have to edit the identical content in one location?

Answer (score 1):

To use a separate single post template for each category, you will need to add the following function in your functions.php:

```
/**
* Define a constant path to our single template folder
*/
define(SINGLE_PATH, TEMPLATEPATH . '/single');

/**
* Filter the single_template with our custom function
*/
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');

/**
* Single template function which will choose our template
*/
function my_single_template($single) {
global $wp_query, $post;

/**
* Checks for single template by category
* Check by category slug and ID
*/
foreach((array)get_the_category() as $cat) :

if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php';

elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'))
return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php';

endforeach;
```

This code will tell the script to look for templates such as single-cat-uncategorized.php or single-cat-1.php within the /single folder. You must make sure that you save the files within the single folder that you will need to create in your theme directory.

[https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.bg/2015/09/post-type-templates.html)